# Set Duplicate Values to Null in PostgresSQL retaining one of the values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, unique

I have a database like this:

```
id    name    email
0     Bill    bill@fakeemail.com
1     John    john@fakeemail.com
2     Susan   susan@fakeemail.com
3     Susan J susan@fakeemail.com
```

I want to remove duplicate emails by setting the value to null, but retain at least 1 email on one of the rows (doesn't really matter which one).

So that the resulting database would look like this:

```
id    name    email
0     Bill    bill@fakeemail.com
1     John    john@fakeemail.com
2     Susan   susan@fakeemail.com
3     Susan J
```

I was able to target the rows like this
`SELECT COUNT(email) as count FROM users WHERE count > 1`

But can't figure out how to set the value to null while still retaining at least 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the rows which have the same `email` but greater `id`:

```
update my_table t1
set email = null
where exists (
    select from my_table t2
    where t1.email = t2.email and t1.id > t2.id
    );
```

[Working example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/GPZZM58868)

Comment: What about a database that doesn't have an id? Or the id is a hash?

Comment: Use another column, e.g. `name`. It also may be a hash column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a windowed partition to assign a row number to each email group, and then use that generated row number to modify all rows except for one. Something like this:

```
WITH annotated_persons AS(
SELECT
 id,
 name,
 email,
 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY email) AS i
FROM
 persons;
)
UPDATE persons
SET email = null
WHERE id = annotated_persons.id AND annotated_persons.i <> 1
```

You may have to use another subquery in order to gather the IDs of persons whose row number != 1, and then change your update query to

```
WHERE id IN person_ids
```

It's been awhile since I've used a window.